# How to format spring validation errors to replace <br> delimiter with ", "

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

My web page has a lot of horizontal space next to the fields that are being validated and I want to show all validation errors for one field, separated by a comma.

Currently a typicaly multiple spring error messages are being formatted into html like that:

```
<input id="name" type="text" size="50" value="" name="name"></input>
    <span id="name.errors" class="errText">
       Name cant be blank!
       <br></br>
       Name is required!
    </span>
```

What I want is to specify a format(ter) which would output an error message like this:

```
<input id="name" type="text" size="50" value="" name="name"></input>
    <span id="name.errors" class="errText">
       Name cant be blank!, Name is required!
    </span>
```

Is it possible to do this globally or at least with initBinder method per controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can format error like you want with that code :

```
<spring:bind path="YourFieldPath">
    <c:forEach var="error" items="${status.errorMessages}" varStatus="status">
        ${error}
        <c:if test="${!status.last}">,</c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</spring:bind>
```

Comment: I really don't want to put that next to every field, second that just add a comma and does not remove <br>, and that's hacking really xD, I'm looking to produce a different output not to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline` in CSS

Comment: I put it into errText css class and it doesn't work.